# Web design/development - alternative to manually refreshing the page?

Tags: browser, web, wysiwyg

I wonder if there is a better way to write my PHP sites without always having to manually refresh the page I'm working on. Could there be a program that monitors a folder and automatically refresh my browser whenever a change occurs. I'm developing on a local machine with a local amp stack by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by ajax. In ajax you can check the changes in database if any new record added you can call

```
location.replace('');
```

in ajax success

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax poll (checking for status change on server with time intervals) and when the change occurs, either refresh the page with Javascript or replace the part of it to reflect the change.